# Why choose MySQL over other Sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i wanted to ask a question that i myself have been asked in class by our database teacher;

What makes MySQL different from other Sqls? I've always been using MySQL due to the fact that's what we have been taught when i learned how to program websites, but honestly? I dont know what makes MySQL better then other SQL's(For program development) such as;

- SQLite
- MS Access
- PostgreSQL
- MongoDB

I was hoping someone could point me towards the answer or perhaps even give me a explanation of it.

I hope it was alright to post this question here as i'm unsure as to were else it should have been posted.

Comment: MongoDB is not a relational (SQL) database.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Comment: I don't see any reason to choose MySQL over PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL's language features are far more advanced than MySQL's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd choose MySQL over

- SQLite, because SQLite is too "lite" for a lot of purposes; it does not have multi-user access, so would not work quite well in server environment
- MS Access and PostgreSQL, because they are less common and I'm more likely to get useful community support for them (especially valid for MS Access :-)
- MongoDB, because that is not SQL database at all, and you've asked about SQL databases

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Che. :) That really helped ^^ Its pretty much impossible to find the answer online.. That or i phrase my questions horribly.